# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string convert from base64

Tags: c#, sql-server, base64, data-conversion

I have converted an image to a Base64 string using a tool found here
https://codebeautify.org/base64-encode and inserted into a (varchar(max)) column within a (2015 SQL Server) table. The execution of the SQL insert has no issues itself and is successful. The problem occurs within my C# program (VS 2019)  when an attempt is made to convert the base64 string using the following code:

```
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
```

I am receiving the Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string error. I've attempted to add padding to the end of the string based on some previous posts but I've had no luck.

**Update **
I have resolved the issue. I found a different convert tool which worked for me. https://elmah.io/tools/base64-image-encoder/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-5.0 - you don't need to copypasta things off some website - probably where the error crept in. Compare the forward conversion that c# does with the value in the DB, something will be wrong

Comment: I've attempted a second solution with no luck. We currently have a process that uses a Base64 string representation of an image and uses the previously listed Convert function with no issues. That base64 string is stored in the same SQL table / column that I'm using. I have copied that string and updated my record with it and no luck.

Comment: I didn't quite understand this "copied the ..." - why not just execute a `var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO x VALUES(@b64str)", connstr)`, `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b64str", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("path/to.image")));` ? Then you can download it, Convert.FromB64String, and see if it works.. and if it does, feel free to compare the in db value to this value you're copying off some website...

Comment: within SSMS I've executed a simple Select Image from Table and in the output window the result set contains the image column which I copied the string and attempted to do an update , also within SSMS, to my Image record using that string that I just copied.

Comment: You know that SSMS grid cells are length limited, right? All this "copy here", "copy there" is only going to make your life hard work, especially working with stuff like image data, which will quite easily go over whatever limit is configured in your SSMS; if you'd done the read and the write in C# from the outset, you'd be finished already...

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is not a standard but an approach with a number of implementations.  At a guess all you will be short of (please appreciate the pun) is some padding - usually '=' characters.  If this doesn't work, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for background.

In general you must ensure that the encoder and decoder use the same character sets (see article section on variants) and padding convention.